# How to create a multidimensional array from a matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix

```
q = [1 2 3  4  5  6;
     7 8 9 10 11 12];
```

and I want to create an array d such that

```
d(:,:,1) =  1  2
            7  8
d(:,:,2) =  3  4
            9 10 
d(:,:,3) =  5  6
           11 12
```

I know how to do that using loops but i prefer not to use loops.

Answer (score 7):

With `reshape`

```
out = reshape(q,size(q,1),2,[])
```

Comment: Very nice. +1.  Be prepared to not get an accept for your answer though.  This OP is known not to accept any answers because he's a n00b.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for you vote :) Votes from 'the' legends are more valuable to me than answer getting accepted :) BTW, how do you know if an user has accepted any answer without viewing all the questions he asked? There should be a way right?

Comment: Heh thanks :) I wouldn't really consider myself a legend.  I only started answering less than a year ago.  I looked at all of the questions the OP asked.  This OP doesn't have very many: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3988119/mohamed?tab=questions - The questions with a green box indicate that an answer has been given, but there are none with green **and yellow text**.  The yellow text symbolizes that the OP has accepted an answer.  The OP has not accepted any answers since the OP started... and a lot of the questions he asked has good answers. It's a pet peeve, but nothing I can do about that

Comment: @rayryeng That **yellow text** i just noticed. Was very helpful. Thanks :)